# AWS Rekognition : How to compare two Vehicles

Tags: amazon-rekognition, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am trying to compare two Vehicles using AWS-Recognition, I tried various models, Is there any in-build model to compare two vehicles. Actually, we want to implement, automated Vehicle claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, while doing some research on this, Amazon does not provide any inbuild API for this like Face-Recognition or Number Reading. We have to build our custom model.

This is called build train and deploy, We have to follow certain steps.

- ### Rekognition custom labels feature
- Collect Images
- Ground Truth for images.
- Labeling of datasets Manual
- Enable automated data labeling
- Creating Datasets
- Create projects
- Train models

Then it has to be an amazon notebook, and Phyton, using. 
Rekognition-SDK.

However, this process is time consuming.